# Why are the power and drag curves called polars?

Tags: aircraft-performance, terminology, theory

See [Wikipedia:Drag polar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_Polar) and [Wikipedia:Polar curve (aviation)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_curve_%28aviation%29) for example.

These curves are not on a [polar coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system). Why are they called polars?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is an historical name.

The first polars were drawn by Otto Lilienthal in polar coordinates.

[Here](http://www.lilienthal-museum.de/olma/34.htm) (sorry, German link) we find an example:

[image]

Comment: Just a follow-up out of curiousity... Do you know what the first "incorrect" borrowing of the term was? Ie. When was first time that a curve drawn on a non-polar coordinate system called a "polar"?

Comment: @user2168 no, I have no idea. I am sorry.

Comment: Lift and drag coefficients are often presented as a function of angle of attack.  Since these values are a function of angle, I call them polars, regardless of whether the plot is created on a Cartesian or polar set of axes.