# What are these points in this drag curve ("Lilienthal'sches Polardiagramm")?

Tags: aerodynamics, ppl, easa

If it matters, this is taken from EASA PPL questions by AustroControl.
So far I think the points correspond to the following situations:

- 1 Inverted Flight (confirmed)
- 2 ???
- 3 Maybe Best Gliding Angle???
- 4 ???
- 5 Slow Flight (confirmed)
- 6 Maybe Stall ???

[image: Tricky Chart]

Comment: Look at what's unique about each point. (2) generates zero lift. (3) is the point of minimum drag. (4) is the point of maximum lift/drag ratio. (5) is the point of maximum lift. Does that steer you in the right direction?

Comment: Thanks. Here's what I think without opening the book.

- 2 stall
- 3 max endurance
- 4 max range speed
-6 this is now even more confusing

Comment: 6 is the stall. 2 is just the zero-lift point (like NASA's zero-g Vomet Comet would want - completely unloading the wing). 4 is a **very** important point to understand: best glide AoA (= speed more or less)!

Comment: Ok, so 5 is CL Max, or the Critical AoA?
Then does this mean that the Blue line then is the Total Drag and in the lower part shows Induced Drag and then in the upper half Parasitic Drag takes over?

Comment: Right on with (5). It's the other way around with drag: parasitic drag dominates at the left side (at (2) it's all parasitic drag since there's no lift to induce any drag). Induced drag dominates to the right at high (positive or negative) AoA.

Comment: Keep in mind that each point just gives the *instantaneous* Cl and Cd, or in the nomenclature of the graph, Ca and Cw, of some particular Angle-of-Attack.   So, point #1 could *certainly* be obtained in non-inverted flight, if the pilot shoved the stick forward suddenly.  The G-load (basically another word for the lift vector) would be negative.  This is not compatible with a *steady-state condition*, unless the aircraft is inverted, but that doesn't mean that the aircraft *must* be inverted to experience this part of the flight envelope.

Comment: Re " So, point #1 could *certainly* be obtained in non-inverted flight, if the pilot shoved the stick forward suddenly." -- most safely demonstrated starting from a steep climb.  Just as you would demonstrate a slightly less extreme version of the maneuver, bringing the wing to the zero-lift angle-of-attack, and bringing the G-load only to zero, rather than to a - value. If you attempt to demonstrate *either* of these maneuvers from normal level flight, in most aircraft you will end up with the aircraft very steeply nose-down and the airspeed rapidly rising toward the red line. Now what to do?

Comment: @TypeIA -- one more key point-- re your comment " (3) is the point of minimum drag." -- actually it is the point of minimum drag *coefficient*.  It can be shown that for steady-state flight, drag *force* is minimized at the point of max L/D or max Cl/Cd.  Likewise, point #5 is the point of max lift *coefficent*, but the only way to say that this also corresponds to the point of max lift *force*, is to constrain the airspeed to somehow magically stay constant, as other parameters (such as A-o-A) vary.

Comment: @UXNoob4eva -- point 5 is Cl max. The blue line can't be described as the curve of "Total Drag". Rather it gives the lift coefficient *and* the drag coefficient of any point on the line. The *left-right* or *horizontal* position of any point on the blue line describes the *drag coefficient* at that point. But that is not the same as the *Total Drag* at that point. See my other comment immediately above for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be more exact, the above figure is taken [from a question catalog](https://aeroclub.at/uploads/download/SPL_Grundlagen_Flug_05_2020.pdf) for the AustroControl PPL theory exam. The catalog is based on the de-facto standard German PPL textbook
[Advanced PPL-Guide 2a - Aerodynamik Flugzeuge](https://www.pilotstore.at/advanced-ppl-guide-aerodynamik-ebook-version.html)  by Aircademy Ldt.

The book itself including the figure is under copyright, so it is best not to post a scan here. The original annotations for the numbers of that figure in the book (*Chapter 2, "Strömung am Tragflügel", Fig. 19*) are:

| number | original annotation (DE) | translated annotation (EN) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Rückenflug | inverted flight |
| 2 | $c_a = 0$, Sturzflug | nose dive |
| 3 | $c_w = min$ |  |
| 4 | $\frac{c_a}{c_w} = max $ |  |
| 5 | $c_a = max$, Langsamflug | slow flight |
| 6 | überzogener Flugzustand | stall |

Comment: Did you provide the English translations of the annotations or are they in the original? "Nose dive" is a surprising / harsh description of zero load factor. (For that matter I'm curious about "Sturzflug": I speak German, but my flight training and experience is USA-based so I'm not sure if this really is the standard term for this scenario.) Nice answer though, +1 for identifying the source material.

Comment: The original annotations are in German („Sturzflug“, etc.). English translations my own (cross-checked at dict.cc).

Comment: @TypeIA -- echoes of my comments to the actual question-- zero lift / zero load factor/ zero G's can certainly be *demonstrated* or *experienced* in conditions other than a vertical dive, but a vertical dive ("nose-dive") is the only situation where  zero lift / zero load factor/ zero G's (as registered on the G-meter which only detects the "up-and-down" component in the aircraft's normal reference frame)  can be *sustained in a steady-state situation*. It's a bit much to expect study materials for a PPL exam to be cognizant of the differences between steady-state and transient conditions.

Answer (score 2):

The graph seems to make more sense for a [non-symmetrical](http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/details?airfoil=goe399-il) airfoil.

1 is clearly a negative angle of attack

2 is no lift but slightly more drag than 3 ... hmm

3 has lift but a little less drag.  Non symmetrical airfoils can generate lift at 0 Angle of Attack, so 2 probably needs to be at a slightly negative AoA for zero lift.  This accounts for the higher drag.

4 is best lift to drag ratio

5 is a higher Coefficient of Lift but proportionally higher drag, which means higher AoA to compensate for *slower flight* (or higher wing loading, such as in a turn).  Point 5 would be at what is known as "stall speed" (really stall AoA).

6 yes, this is stalled

Comment: Re "2 is no lift but slightly more drag than 3 ... hmm"-- yes, as you noted, this would be for a non-symmetrical (cambered) airfoil.  To make zero lift, despite the cambered shape, the airfoil must be plowing along nose-down at a negative angle-of-attack-- more draggy than an A-o-A closer to zero, which would generate some mild amount of lift.  PS I'm not sure what is the significance of the "Lilienthal" reference, but all his wings were *highly* cambered!  (Very thin, with strongly *concave* under-surfaces.)