# What are these points in the Propeller Schematic?

Tags: aerodynamics, propeller, ppl, easa

[image: Propeller Schematic]

If it matters, this is taken from EASA PPL questions.

The graphic appears to be taken from the side point of view, although I've never seen such a round Spinner, unless it's a variable pitch propeller and it's just the ball bearing joint the blade is attached to.

So far my guess is that the points correspond to the following:

1. Angle of Incidence (confirmed)
2. Geometric wing twist (not sure)
3. Angle of Attack (90% sure)
4. Aerodynamic wing twist (not sure)

- C: is Chord line
- D: is Direction of air flow  (I think it refers to the Relative Airflow)
- R: is Direction of rotation (I guess clockwise in this case)

2,3,4 could be any of the following "Geometric wing twist", "Angle of Attack" and "Aerodynamic wing twist"

Comment: Do you have any more context, or is the question simple "label these points"?  Because that would be a really crummy question...

Comment: The gray circle is indeed the joint to which the propeller is attached. The spinner is not shown in this figure.

Comment: If my below explanation answers your question, please mark it so. Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like in [your last question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/94235/28511), you are asking us to label a figure which you have taken from the [Aircademy Ltd. PPL question catalog](https://aircademy.com/en/ecqb-ppl/).

In this case, the figure is from *Part-FCL Question Bank 80 – Aircraft General Knowledge, Question 65*:

[image]

So the one label you have been able to "confirm" is the one already marked out in the question catalog.

What you are looking for to label the remaining points is a *propeller blade section velocity diagram*. A simple one is provided in [Figure 5-44 of the excellent FAA Control Flying Handbook, FAA-H-8083-5](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/phak/media/07_phak_ch5.pdf). More advanced ones are provided in scientific publications, such as [Figure 7 in "An Overview of Model Tests and Numerical Predictions
for Propeller-Ice Interaction"](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/44052367_An_overview_of_model_tests_and_numerical_predictions_for_propeller-ice_interaction)

[image]

> Velocity diagram for a propeller blade section, $\beta$ is the angle of advance, $\beta_i$ is the hydrodynamic pitch angle, $\phi$ is the geometric pitch
> angle, $\alpha_G$ is the geometric angle of attack, $V$ is the carriage speed, $V_A$ is the advance speed,  and $U_A$ are the tangential and axial induced velocities, and $P$ is the pitch at $0.7R$.

In short:

| point | label |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | blade pitch (=angle of incidence) |
| 3 | angle of attack (angle between relative wind and chord line) |

4 and 2 are velocities which are not mentioned in the main course materials and would not be relevant for the exam.

As a general recommendation, I suggest you purchase the [training material (textbooks) by Aircademy Ltd.](https://aircademy.com/en/#!/produkte), since you are clearly preparing for your exam using their question catalogs. The expense will be inconsequential compared to the rest of your training cost - but it would enable you to look up these figures without having to resort to StackExchange multiple times.

Comment: Thanks, do you know if the learning materials come in English too?

Answer (score 0):

None of these are "twist."

If the length R represents the speed of the propeller, then 2 is the "adjacent" side of a triangle, allowing you to calculate the length of D using the Pythagorean formula.

4 represents the forward airspeed of the aircraft in proportion to R, which allows you to calculate 3, the angle of attack.

Comment: "None of these are "twist."
Agreed, but they are now, as this is how the questions were translated.